# Visual Studio Auto Suggesting Twice

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

When I type a variable name it begins to autofill what the variable name is... twice. Does anyone have an idea what setting could be causing this? I am using Resharper Ultimate. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

There are two auto suggetion menus. When I use the arrow keys to move down, only the one in the back enumerates the options.

Comment: I didn't faced that problem, but have you tried to reset VS settings ?

Comment: That does not work.

Comment: Any chance that resharper shows the second menu ?

Comment: It does but I want the resharper one. I found this article which helped me resolve the issue: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206738755-Seeing-2-intellisense-popups

Answer (score 1):

You have to go into the Visual Studio C# 
options (Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C#) and disable statement 
completion (uncheck "Auto list members" and "Parameter Information").